# Reading ID3V2 TAG in c language

Tags: c, id3v2

I am a beginner in programming and I have an assignment from my university to wright a code in C for reading mp3 files in ID3V2 format. I have searched the web and tried to put together some pieces and I came up with this code. Although that I have put many error warnings from top to bottom I can not still understand where is the mistake.

My first problem is that the code it compiles with only one warning: 
warning: format ‘%s’ expects a matching ‘char *’ argument [-Wformat]

Unfortunately I do not know what is my mistake here. I am trying to print the input of the user in case of a mistake, thought by doing this I get this warning.

My second problem is when I am executing the code I get as an output:
The program has failed to get the Tags

Any help would much appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your time reading my problem.

Best Regards,
Thanos

This is my code so far:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    typedef struct{
    char tag[3];
    char title[30];
    char artist[30];
    char album[30];
    char year[4];
    char comment[30];
    unsigned char genre;
    }mp3Info;

    int main (int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    if ( argc != 1 ) /* Input from user argc should be 1 for correct
    *execution. The argument count variable
    * stores the number of arguments plus one. */ 
    {
    /*We print argv[0], if the program that user has chosen for
     * execution it is not correct as input if has more inputs*/ 
    printf( "Please choose one file: %s <silence.mp3> \n", argv[0] );
    }
    else 
    {
    FILE *file; /* A file pointer is a variable of type FILE, 
    * we declare a file pointer.*/

    file = fopen("silence.mp3", "rb"); /* Open the file
    * silence.mp3 in
    * "reading" mode "r". */

    if (file == NULL) {
    /* If the file could not open for a variety of reasons
     * the program should inform us by print the document
     * and exit.*/ 
    printf("I couldn't open: %s for reading.\n");
    exit(0);
    }

    else 
    {
    mp3Info tag_in;

    /* Set the fseek to the beggining of the document with
     * the help of the command SEEK_SET, condition if fail*/

    if (fseek(file, 0 *sizeof(mp3Info), SEEK_SET) == -1)
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "Not able to fseek");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Read the first name "tag" */
    if (fread(&tag_in, sizeof(mp3Info), 1, file) != 1)
    {
    printf("Could not read the tag\n");
    exit (0);
    }

    /* Compare memory areas for verification */

    if (memcmp(tag_in.tag, "TAG", 3) == 0)
    {
    /* Verify that names are where as we expect */
    printf("Title: %.30s\n", tag_in.title);
    printf("Artist: %.30s\n", tag_in.artist);
    printf("Album: %.30s\n", tag_in.album);
    printf("Year: %.4s\n", tag_in.year);

    if (tag_in.comment[28] == '\0')

    {
    printf("Comment: %.28s\n", tag_in.comment);
    printf("Track: %d\n", tag_in.comment[29]);
    }

    else
    {
    printf("Comment: %.30s\n", tag_in.comment);
    }
    printf("Genre: %d\n", tag_in.genre);
    }

    else
    {
    fprintf(stderr, "The program has failed to get the Tags\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fclose(file);
    return 0;

    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You confused ID3v1 with ID3v2 formats.

Answer (score 1):

The warning you're getting is in reference to this line (which you could have determined from the line number you left out of the error message):

```
printf("I couldn't open: %s for reading.\n");
```

You're specifying with `%s` that a string will be passed as an argument, but you aren't passing that string you promised.

The failure of your program suggests that the file you're giving it doesn't have an ID3 tag where you expect it. This is because the ID3v1 tag you're trying to read (not ID3v2; that's a totally different format) is typically located at the *end* of the file, not the beginning. To read it, you'll need to seek to near the end of the file, instead of to the beginning:

```
fseek(file, -sizeof(mp3Info), SEEK_END);
```

Comment: Dear duskwuff, Thank you for the immediate reply to my problem. I am trying to write a code to read an ID3V2 mp3 file. If I am not mistaken the information of the tags are at the beginning of the file. that is why I used '(fseek(file, 0 *sizeof(mp3Info), SEEK_SET) == -1)'. I am sorry for Confusions if I did explain correct that I am trying to create an ID3v2 code.

Comment: The structure that you've specified in `mp3Info` is an ID3v1 tag. ID3v2 tags are considerably more complex, and don't have a fixed size or order.

Comment: Dear duskwuff, thank you again for your time reading and replying to my request. I have asked a friend for some guidance and he advised me the best source is to read first to make it and then step by step try to implement it. [link](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-structure). Again thank you for your time and effort.